# How to use select() to get a logical variable out of a dataset

Tags: r

I am having trouble separating portions of my dataset based on non-numerical variables. My question is this: how do I select a portion of variables from a dataset that are not related to numbers?

This is the data I am working with:

```
structure(list
(Ferret.ID = c(558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 
558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 560L, 
560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 
560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 
561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 562L, 562L, 
562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 
562L, 562L, 562L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 
563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
564L, 564L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 
565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 
574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 
574L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 
542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 542L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 
543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 543L, 
544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 
544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 544L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 
545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 545L, 546L, 
546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 
546L, 546L, 546L, 546L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 
547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 547L, 548L, 548L, 
548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 
548L, 548L, 548L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 
549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L, 549L), 
Vaccine = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("None", 
"Vaccine"), class = "factor"), 
Day = c(-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 
20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 
20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), 
Temperature = c(100.6, 101.5, 101.9, 101.2, 
101.8, 101.9, 101.8, 102.1, 102, 100.6, 100.7, 101.7, 101.6, 
103.5, 103.1, 100.6, 102.3, 102, 100.1, 101.7, 102.2, 101.8, 
100.7, 101.2, 101.7, 100.8, 100.4, 100.7, 101, 104.6, 101.5, 
100.8, 102.5, 102.7, 100.8, 100.5, 102.1, 102.4, 101.5, 102.1, 
102.1, 100.2, 100.5, 100.9, 102, 104.4, 102.2, 99.8, 101.3, 101.5, 
101.9, 102.5, 102.1, 101.8, 101.6, 101.9, 102.6, 100.6, 101.4, 
100.5, 101.8, 104.7, 103.1, 100.6, 103.2, 103.7, 102.5, 102.7, 
101.5, 102.4, 102, 100.9, 101.8, 100.2, 102.8, 100.8, 102.8, 
105.1, 103.3, 101.2, 102, 102.2, 101.5, 102.3, 102, 101.4, 100.6, 
101.6, 101.3, 101.7, 102, 101.6, 101.6, 103.2, 103.4, 100.7, 
102, 102.3, 102.3, 100.5, 103, 102.8, 102.9, 101.5, 102.4, 102.4, 
101.2, 102, 102.1, 104, 102.1, 101.5, 102.5, 102.2, 101.9, 102.7, 
102.5, 102.7, 102.2, 102.2, 102.1, 101.6, 101, 102.4, 102, 104.5, 
103.1, 101.2, 100.1, 100.7, 100.5, 100.4, 101.8, 100.9, 100.6, 
101.1, 101.5, 100.2, 100.1, 101.5, 101.9, 102.7, 102.3, 99.4, 
100.7, 101.1, 100.5, 101.6, 102.4, 102, 99.5, 102.3, 102.8, 100.4, 
101.3, 100.9, 101.8, 103.2, 101.9, 102.3, 102.6, 102.2, 101, 
101.5, 102.2, 101.7, 101.3, 101.3, 103.2, 100.8, 100, 101.5, 
101.6, 103.3, 102.7, 101.8, 100.5, 101.1, 101.6, 101.6, 102.3, 
102.2, 101.4, 100.9, 102.1, 100.5, 100.5, 100.7, 102.5, 103, 
102.1, 99.8, 101.4, 101.7, 101.6, 102.7, 102.8, 102.4, 102.2, 
102.8, 102.9, 103, 101.4, 102.1, 102, 104.2, 103.2, 102, 102.6, 
102.5, 100.2, 101, 101.8, 101.4, 100.2, 100.8, 101.9, 101.3, 
102.2, 101, 101, 101.6, 101.5, 100.8, 100.7, 101.2, 101.6, 101.5, 
101.9, 101.6, 101.7, 102.2, 100.8, 100, 101, 101.7, 101, 103.3, 
101.1, 101.7, 101.2, 101.6, 100.4, 101.6, 102, 101.6, 101.5, 
101.8, 101.7, 101.9, 102.2, 101.3, 102.3, 101.4, 101.8, 101.4), 
Weight = c(1420L, 1420L, 1390L, 1380L, 1400L, 1390L, 1400L, 
1400L, 1450L, 1440L, 1420L, 1420L, 1410L, 1390L, 1350L, 1240L, 
1060L, 1060L, 1070L, 1060L, 1050L, 1060L, 1020L, 1070L, 1110L, 
1150L, 1130L, 1130L, 1110L, 1090L, 1050L, 1000L, 1050L, 1040L, 
1050L, 1050L, 1050L, 1050L, 1040L, 1020L, 1040L, 1100L, 1100L, 
1120L, 1080L, 990L, 1020L, 990L, 1100L, 1100L, 1090L, 1110L, 
1100L, 1100L, 1080L, 1080L, 1090L, 1130L, 1110L, 1100L, 1090L, 
1080L, 1030L, 990L, 1500L, 1440L, 1400L, 1410L, 1420L, 1410L, 
1370L, 1410L, 1420L, 1450L, 1400L, 1440L, 1420L, 1380L, 1360L, 
1360L, 1100L, 1100L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1080L, 1110L, 
1120L, 1150L, 1140L, 1130L, 1130L, 1120L, 1110L, 1080L, 1050L, 
1060L, 1060L, 1050L, 1060L, 1060L, 1040L, 1060L, 1060L, 1060L, 
1080L, 1080L, 1070L, 1040L, 1020L, 1040L, 1140L, 1150L, 1160L, 
1170L, 1180L, 1170L, 1130L, 1180L, 1170L, 1200L, 1190L, 1200L, 
1200L, 1150L, 1120L, 1090L, 1180L, 1180L, 1160L, 1170L, 1170L, 
1180L, 1240L, 1230L, 1230L, 1230L, 1230L, 1250L, 1240L, 1240L, 
1230L, 1210L, 1230L, 1250L, 1240L, 1260L, 1270L, 1270L, 1280L, 
1280L, 1290L, 1270L, 1260L, 1270L, 1260L, 1230L, 1260L, 1290L, 
1000L, 1030L, 990L, 1010L, 1000L, 1000L, 990L, 1000L, 980L, 980L, 
980L, 960L, 950L, 930L, 930L, 930L, 1200L, 1210L, 1180L, 1200L, 
1200L, 1220L, 1230L, 1230L, 1250L, 1250L, 1220L, 1230L, 1220L, 
1210L, 1230L, 1220L, 1500L, 1060L, 1070L, 1090L, 1100L, 1100L, 
1110L, 1130L, 1130L, 1130L, 1120L, 1110L, 1199L, 1090L, 1100L, 
1110L, 1080L, 1080L, 1070L, 1100L, 1100L, 1100L, 1130L, 1140L, 
1090L, 1120L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1080L, 1080L, 1100L, 1290L, 
1300L, 1320L, 1031L, 1310L, 1300L, 1300L, 1280L, 1270L, 1230L, 
1250L, 1250L, 1220L, 1080L, 1200L, 1200L, 890L, 870L, 860L, 820L, 
800L, 800L, 850L, 850L, 830L, 830L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 820L, 820L, 
820L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -256L))
```

I am trying to find the mean temperature of the vaccinated and not vaccinated ("None") ferrets. However I cannot find a way to seperate the data based on a logical factor like "Vaccinated" and "Not Vaccinated". How do I do this?
I have tried something like this but its not working:

```
mean(subset(Ferrets, Ferrets$Vaccine="Vaccine", 
  select = c('Vaccine', 'Day', 'Temperature')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the mean temperature and day by `Ferret.ID`?

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Vaccine) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(Temperature))
```

Comment: Sorry, i omitted a word in the OP. I am looking for the mean temperature of both vaccinated and non vaccinated ferrets

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:
Let's define your data by "data_question"

```
library(dplyr)
data_question %>% 
  group_by(Vaccine) %>% 
  summarise(mean_day = mean(Day),
            mean_temperature = mean(Temperature),
            mean_weight = mean(Weight))
```

Also, if you prefer, there is no need to choose new variable names, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data_question %>% 
  group_by(Vaccine) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Day),
            mean(Temperature),
            mean(Weight))
```